# dask concat not supported in latest version

Tags: dask

I am trying to test the dask commands found on this page...

https://extrapolations.dev/blog/2015/07/reproduceit-reddit-word-count-dask/

I got an error at this line:

> words = bodies.map(nltk.word_tokenize).concat()

I guess the dask API has changed since the article was published. How do I rewrite it using this file...

aws s3 cp s3://reddit-comments/2007/RC_2007-10 .

I have managed to run this code so far:

```
import re
import json
import time
import nltk
import dask
import dask.bag as db
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

data = db.read_text("RC_2007-10" ).map(json.loads)
no_stopwords = lambda x: x not in stopwords.words('english')

is_word = lambda x: re.search("^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$", x) is not None

subreddit = data.filter(lambda x: x['subreddit'] == 'movies')
bodies = subreddit.pluck('body')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for the flatten method:

```
In [1]: import dask.bag as db                                                   

In [2]: b = db.from_sequence([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])                            

In [3]: b.flatten().compute()                                                   
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag-api.html